# In the public key cryptography, number of keys required for secure communication between n parties will be?

Tags: algorithm, encryption, public-key-encryption

In the public key cryptography, number of keys required for secure communication between n parties will be?

In my view the answer should be n*n (or n^2 or n squared)

Reason:
There are ‘n’ Parties.
Every Party has One (1) Public Key (for Encryption).
Also, every Party has n-1 private keys (paired) (for Decryption)
So every party has 1 + n-1 = n keys, and there are n parties communicating.
No. of Keys required is = n x n = n^2.
So Am I correct? (Please be specific & also show the full logic & give proper explanations).

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about  cryptography and doesn't include a programming problem.

Comment: It is about Cryptography only! I am sorry if I have done a mistake, But some one said I should post it here, as here are many experts here!

Comment: You may find http://crypto.stackexchange.com/ to be a better fit. But please check their Help Center before posting to ensure your question is on-topic.

Answer (score 0):

`n` key pairs is enough.

Every party generates a private/public key pair and publishes the public part.
When Alice wants to communicate with Bob, she encrypts her message with Bobs public key and now only Bob (not even Alice!) can decrypt it.

I think you are confusing this with secret key (aka symmetric) crypto, where every communication channel must have its own key, and there are `n*(n-1)/2` channels for `n` parties.

Comment: Why answer a completely off-topic question? You should be voting to close and moving on...

Comment: @Duncan: you might be right... An irresistible urge to share knowledge overcame me. Sorry.

Comment: Easily done. But it has the side effect of encouraging people to continue to ask these questions. Hopefully this will be closed soon. I'd suggest you delete your answer, even though it's correct.

Comment: For God's sake, why downvoting? Thanks @sds for your answer. Could you just elaborate that in practice,  symmetric keys are generated and exchanged using the public/private keys.

Comment: Guys, I had asked for Asymmetric one! Still, Thanks!
Ok I have cleared my doubts! So One can Close this, But don't Downvote or Block me!